# Android - why isn't bitmap loading time much shorter when image is smaller and more compressed?

Tags: android, image, performance, android-layout, bitmap

I'm making an app for android. I use images as screen background.
Time of setting 1848x1080 jpg in imageView is about 65-80ms on my phone. File size is 900kb.

When I reduce image's quality and size (1369x800), the size of file is about 150kb.

But time of loading that image is about 55-60ms! Not much of a difference.

Why is that? Can anyone help me with this - how to prepare images well to be loaded as quickly as possible in android and still look well on Full HD screen?

Answer (score 0):

That is because Android as an operating system has to create an internal file descriptor in each case. That takes always the same time, so you don't win anything if the file size changes.

I would recommend you to preload the files you quickly need and hold them in the memory (caching). This will maybe blow up the memory used by your app, but it will allow you to display those images really fast.